# How to write simple TCP listener that will be able to send packages ?

Tags: c#

I need to write simple TCP listener that will be able to listen TCP ( receive packages ) on one thread and in case i need to send some package i will be able to do it on some other thread

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [TcpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx) class. It has asynchronous versions of the methods such as [BeginAcceptTcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.beginaccepttcpclient.aspx) which will in turn give you an instance of a [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) on which you could call [GetStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream.aspx) to reach the underlying stream and from there on continue using the asynchronous versions on this stream to [BeginRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.beginread.aspx) and [BeginWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.beginwrite.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

One simple project that might guide you:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/TCPIPChat.aspx